# SQL Server trusted connection has wrong user in IIS, but SSMS is OK

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis-7.5, credentials

I am using VS 2012, connecting to SQL Server 2008 host using windows credentials. I can connect fine from Management Studio, but when I run a web application (IIS 7.5 windows 7 ASP.NET 4.0 integrated) and my application tries to connect, I get this:

> Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyMachineName$'.

For some reason IIS App pool using Network Identity is not using MyUserName but my machine name instead.  My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="Assignment" 
         connectionString="Data Source=a.b.c.d;Initial Catalog=My_Db;Trusted_Connection=true;Max Pool Size=200;Pooling=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I should mention this is a new (to me) computer. I looked in credential manager and there is nothing there. Any ideas why IIS and my web app using the wrong thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS is actually doing exactly what it was designed to do when you run your app pool under the Network Service identity.

> Using the Network Service account in a domain environment has a great
> benefit. Worker process running as Network Service access the network
> as the machine account. Machine accounts are generated when a machine
> is joined to a domain. They look like this:
>
> `<domainname>\<machinename>$`,
>
> For example: mydomain\machine1$
>
> The nice thing about this is that network resources
> like file shares or SQL Server databases can be ACLed to allow this
> machine account access.

The quote above is from the following documentation...

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Hopefully this answers the question of why it isn't working the way you expect.

As far as how to make it work the way you want, I think this article should answer that question, and if not, some basic google searching should come up with quite a bit of information on how to properly configure your environment for what you're trying to do.

https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/allowing-iis-7-5-applications-to-communicate-to-sql-server-via-windows-authentication/

Comment: Thanks @Jim! So this means that Sql Server _only_ authenticates against the machine name in trusted connection, right?  That makes sense for a web server.  In this case I wanted it to log in the same way SMS does in windows authentication mode.  It doesn't sound like there is a way to make it do this. Since this is a remote server the second article won't help me.

Comment: @Jim When we I try to add  'IIS...' to database it throws up error 'Windows NT user or group 'IIS ..' not found'

Comment: @singhswat my solution was to create a sql user and use the connection string for that user instead of windows domain pass-through.  My question wasn't so much how to solve it as why is behavior different in IIS vs. SSMS.  The answer is that IIS runs as network service so trust is based on machine and not user.

Comment: Awesome. 3 year old answer and somehow I found it after days of google search. Creating a user for IIS app pool works.